# Angular2 http : Not able to Understad why I am getting user array with one piece of code and user object at a time with the another?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-http

first :

```
 this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users).
        map(users=>users.json())
        .subscribe(
        users=>{
        let user : User=users[0];
        console.log(user);
        })
```

second :

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users')
   .flatMap((resp:Response)=>resp.json())
   .filter((user : User)=>user.username==this.userName)
   .subscribe(
   (user : User)=>{
   console.log(user.username);
   })
```

I hope with subscribe I should be getting them each one at a time . Please let me know where i am wrong.

Comment: In the second you apply the flatMap operator, did you readed the documentation for it? that answers your question

Comment: Thanks @Jota.Toledo . However I couldn't understand much from the documentation but it is due to functionality of flatMap as I understood from some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening due to flatMap operator. A small example to illustrate this where we are getting one user object at a time :

```
this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:3000/users")
.flatMap(users=>{
return Object.values(users)})
.subscribe(
user=>{
this.users.push(user);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the url you are requesting, the first one passes the `username` so your query will return a single user, in the second url your are not filtering down the results from the back-end but by the `filter` method on the `Observable` so it will return all users from back-end as an array then select only one that matches your filter.

You can access each user's data using a `for-of` loop like below:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users')
   .flatMap((resp:Response)=>resp.json())
   .subscribe(
   (users : User[])=> {
        for (let user of users) {
            console.log(user.username); 
        }
   })
```

Or you can remove the `filter` part of your second query and filter manually inside the `subscribe` body.